# Copy files based on regex to another folder but keep folder structure

Tags: copy, sh, filepath

I want to copy files matching a regex to another folder but while keeping part of the folder structure, All the filepaths will start with src/main/java/ buth the path before that is different for most files

I know that I can use

```
find . -iregex ".*HeadersConstants\.java" -exec cp {} ./destination/ \;
```

To copy a file but then I lose the file path in the destination dir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you on linux? Historically, `cpio` would have been an obvious choice but these days rsync is likely to be better:

```
find . -iregex ".*HeadersConstants\.java" |\
rsync -v --files-from=- ./ ${destination}/
```

It's probaby not a good idea for the destination to be inside `.` as your question code suggests but we can stop find looking there with:

```
find . -path ./destination -prune \
    -o -iregex ".*HeadersConstants\.java" -print |\
rsync -v --file-from=- ./ ./destination/
```

(You may want to investigate why the `-print` is required.)

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I got it to work (probably not the cleanest way)

```
javaRe='(.*)\/src\/main\/java\/(.*)\/'
find . -name "HeadersConstants\.java" | while read f
do
    if [[ ${f} =~ ${javaRe} ]]; then
        path=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
        fullpath=${destination}${srcDir}${path}
        mkdir -p "$fullpath"
        cp "$f" "$fullpath"
    fi
done
```